# Display list of Menu Permissions from table - replacing RoleId and UserId with RoleName and UserName in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I have a Menu that populates bases on Username or Roles. I would like to generate a list table of the SQL entries. Standard foreach, using a ViewModel that i generated. I think this can be simplified and maybe some items added to the 'ViewModel' to achieve this but i am not getting this correct.

Below is the View model, the db.MenuPermissions has ForeinKeys:
RoleId - AspNetRoles(Id) 
UserId - AspnetUsers(Id)

```
public class MenuPermissionView
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string MenuId { get; set; }
    public virtual Menu Menu_MenuId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Role")]
    public string RoleId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("User")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Sort Order")]
    public int? SortOrder { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Is For Nav Bar")]
    public bool IsForNavBar { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Is Add")]
    public bool IsAdd { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Is Create")]
    public bool IsCreate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Is Read")]
    public bool IsRead { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Is Update")]
    public bool IsUpdate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Is Delete")]
    public bool IsDelete { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the controller (Not Complete) I feel this could be cleaner and it clearly does not work the way it is.
I have tried to add Identity for roles and users but that did not seem to help. I would also like for it to just return a list and not a staticPagedList with values, I will be using dataTables that will take care of that.

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<MenuPermissionView> col_Mem = new List<MenuPermissionView>();

        var role = RoleManager.Roles
            .ToList();
        var user = UserManager.Users
            .ToList();
        var result = 

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            MenuPermissionView objRoles = new MenuPermissionView();

            objRoles.Menu_MenuId = item.Menu_menuId;
            objRoles.RoleId = item.Name;
            objRoles.UserId = item.Users;
            objRoles.IsForNavBar = item.IsForNavbar;
            objRoles.IsAdd = item.IsAdd;
            objRoles.IsCreate = item.IsCreate;
            objRoles.IsDelete = item.IsDelete;
            objRoles.IsRead = item.IsRead;
            objRoles.IsUpdate = item.IsUpdate;

            col_Mem.Add(objRoles);
        }

        return View(col_Mem.ToPagedList(5, 25));

        //return View(db.MenuPermissions.ToList());
    }
```

I could achieve this if it were only using tables that i have models for, however these tables to not have models because they are part of Entity Frameworks Identities.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am going a different direction with this and am using SQL views to display what i want. It seems to be easier to implement. Also changing every thing over to stored procedures. I will not be using linq very much if at all.

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is that you are foreaching on item that you are just creating
you may get the reult from the database and foreach on the result